# Is there a name for elements $x$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f$ behaves differently on each side of $x$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization, roots, graphing-functions

Let $f : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote a continuous function. Suppose $x \in (a,b)$ satisfies $f(x)=0$. Then there exists $r>0$ such that:

- The restriction of $f$ to $[x,x+r)$ is either consistently $\geq 0$, consistently $=0$, or consistently $\leq 0$.
- The restriction of $f$ to $(x-r,x]$ is either consistently $\geq 0$, consistently $=0$, or consistently $\leq 0$.

Now in practice, we're often only interested in those zeros such that the answer is different on the left and right. For instance, if $f(x)$ is negative on the left of $x$ and positive on the right, that's an important zero of $f$. But if $f$ is negative on both the left and the right of $x$, there are situations where this zero can safely be ignored. For example, if we're looking for the turning points of $f(x)$, some of the zeroes of $f'(x)$ can be ignored, because they correspond to points of inflection of $f(x)$ and hence aren't relevant to the problem. If you think about it for a bit, you'll see that it's really the roots of $f'(x)$ that are "non-trivial", in the sense of having different behavior on each side, that matter with respect to the problem of minimizing and maximizing $f(x)$ on an interval.

My question, quite simply, is:

> **Question.** For continuous $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is there a name for those zeroes of $f$ such that it behaves differently on each side of that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got dragged here by wondering who asked a different question, and then looking at some of @goblin's other questions.

I just want to note that the first statement about $f$ is false, which makes the rest of the question sort of moot, although @AntonioVargas's suggestion of "weakly changes sign" is a good term for something related to @goblin's original question.

To see that the first statement of the question is false, 
look at the function

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x = 0 \\
x^2sin(\frac{1}{x}) & x \ne 0
\end{cases}.
$$

It is differentiable at $0$ (with derivative $0$ there), but for every $r > 0$, there are points of the interval $[0, r)$ where $f$ is positive, negative, and zero. (To find them, look for the first integer multiple of $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ that's larger than $1/r$. Call this $u$. Then $f(u) = 0$, and $f(u^{+}) < 0$ and $f(u^{-}) > 0$, where $u^{\pm}$ denote any small-enough perturbations of $u$.)

Comment: That's an excellent counterexample (serves me right for not proving "obvious" facts...), but I wouldn't say the question is moot. It just means we need more restrictions on $f$.

Comment: That one function is a counterexample to almost *everything*. :)

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about it. It was probably mentioned in the real analysis classes I took like four years ago, but I probably wasn't paying attention. I feel that way about a lot of real analysis, actually - for example, it's taken me this long to appreciate that the mean value theorem is actually, you know, important...

Answer (score 0):

Commonly we say that $f$ **changes sign** at such a point $x$. This would mean that $f(x) = 0$ and that there is some $r > 0$ such that either

- $f(t) < 0$ for $t \in (x-r,x)$ and $f(t) > 0$ for $t \in (x,x+r)$, or
- $f(t) > 0$ for $t \in (x-r,x)$ and $f(t) < 0$ for $t \in (x,x+r)$.

Comment: It needn't. Consider $x \mapsto \max\{0,x\}$, for example.

Comment: @goblin, there isn't a common phrase for the specific notion that you imagine. If you need one, you could create your own, something like "we say $f$ **weakly changes sign** at $x$ if..."