# Is every "changeling" of $f$ also a zero of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis

> **Definition 0.** Let $$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ denote a function, and suppose we're given $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}.$
>
> Then the *left sign* of $f$ at $x_0$ is $$f^L(x_0) = \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^-} \mathrm{sign}(f(x)),$$ and the *right sign* of $f$ at $x_0$ is $$f^R(x_0) = \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^+} \mathrm{sign}(f(x)),$$ whenever these limits exist.

I'm interested in those inputs $x \in \mathbb{R}$ at which the left and right signs of $f$ disagree.

So define that:

> **Definition 1.** A *changeling* of $f$ is an $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the left and right signs of $f$ at $x_0$ exist, and $$f^L(x_0) \neq f^R(x_0).$$

Not every zero of $f$ will necessarily be a changeling; for example, $x^2$ has a zero at $x:=0$ that isn't a changeling. On the other hand, it seems intuitively clear that every changeling of $f$ should also be a zero of $f$. But I'm having trouble proving this, though.

> **Question.** Is every changeling of $f$ also a zero of $f$, and if so, how can we prove this?

By the way, [I'd be interested to know if changelings have an accepted name](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171303/is-there-a-name-for-elements-x-such-that-fx-0-and-f-behaves-differently).

Comment: You cannot prove it without condition of continuity.

Comment: @Crostul, I'm happy to include this if necessary. A counterexample proving necessity would also be nice.

Comment: @goblin: Consider e.g. $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{when }x<0 \\ 1 & \text{when }x\ge 0\end{cases} $$

Comment: @HenningMakholm, ah yes. How obvious :)

Comment: Every discontinuity that straddles the axis can be a zero-free changeling.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x)= \begin{cases} -1 & x<0 \\ 1 & x\ge0\end{cases}$$

Clearly $f$ has no zero, but $0$ is a changeling of $f$.

However, in the case when $f$ is continuous at the changeling $x_0$, you can show that $f(x_0)=0$ arguing by contradiction:

suppose $f(x_0) <0$. By continuity, there is some neighbourhood of $x_0$ where $f<0$, constradicting that on the left (or on the right) of $x_0$ you have $f>0$.
Similarly you can exclude the case $f(x_0)>0$, hence necessarily $f(x_0)=0$.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, this is a version of the _intermediate value theorem_.

Comment: @Arthur You are right, but it's not so obvious that the zero of $f$ coincides with $x_0$. You know that at every neighbourhood of $x_0$ there is a zero, then you should take the limit... Too long and confusing.

Comment: Isn't that how you prove the IVT in the first place? In that light it seems like exactly the least amount of long and confusing you can get away with.